# If (random) word is not there, completely repeat/restart function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making this random username generator thing because i can and it has options and stuff and one of them is to make sure one of the words in the name is one the user types in an input, but I can't get it to work.

I used .search() to find out if its already there, but I can't get it to repeat the function.

Now, I'm pretty sure all I need is to completely repeat or restart the function, about right here

```
  if(n="-1") {
      // ?????
  }
```

Here's the whole code:

```
function makeName() {
  var typed = document.getElementById("field1").value;
  var first = [/*1ST PART OF NAMES */];
  var second = [ /*2ND PART OF NAME*/ ];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*first.length);
  var sand = Math.floor(Math.random()*second.length);
  var right = first[rand];
  var wrong = second[sand];
  var str = right + wrong;
  var n = str.search(typed);
  if(n="-1") {
      /* here's where i'm stumped pretty much 
         i need to restart the function here i think */
  }
  document.getElementById("field2").value= str;
  $("#result").fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Either javascript or jquery or whatever really would work so long as it does really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
function makeName() {
  var typed = document.getElementById("field1").value;
  var first = [/*1ST PART OF NAMES */];
  var second = [ /*2ND PART OF NAME*/ ];

  // use a loop and move the calculating code inside it
  // initialize the variables so that it will not break on first iteration
  var n = -1;
  var str = '';
  while (n==-1) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*first.length);
    var sand = Math.floor(Math.random()*second.length);
    var right = first[rand];
    var wrong = second[sand];
    str = right + wrong;
    n = str.search(typed);
  }

  document.getElementById("field2").value= str;
  $("#result").fadeIn("fast");
}
```

but you will also need to make sure your code will not repeat forever

---

Beside the *restarting* i am not sure the function performs the task you describe in your question..

You are randomly merging a word from `first` and a word from `second` and check if the `typed` string is found in there..

If you want to check against a list, you will need to not randomly select items, but iterate over all of them until it is found..

You might want to use a regular `for` loop for each array and match against each item in them..

Answer (score 2):

`n = "-1"` is an assignment - and it always evaluates to boolean `true` (as '-1' string is considered truthy value in JS).

`n === -1`, however, is a comparison, and that's probably what you need here. No need to compare with string "-1" - `search` (as well as `indexOf` - btw, the latest is far better fit here) always returns a Number.

Comment: You don't need the whole function to restart - just a part of it that creates that random value IF the random value you have is not what you want. One approach is to place that part in `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

you have to compare  use  `n == "-1"`

Answer (score 1):

When You compare values You must use double == instead of single =
So the error is in the line :

```
if(n="-1")
```

it should be :

```
if(n == -1)
```